# Adding Ram Laptop running 16.04

Tags: ram

My laptop currently has 4gb of RAM and desire to increase to 8gb, ordered RAM at local computer store that was indicated to be same as existing (sodimm, DDR3 etc) just different brand. Removed old RAM installed the new RAM and tried to boot Ubuntu 16.04. Booted to Grub (normally does not) hit enter and boot continued for few seconds and crashed with power off of laptop and after few seconds powered on and did same all over again had to power off manually to shut down. I booted into BIOS and ran memory tested and it passed, would assume if can boot to BIOS then Ubuntu should boot but does not. Reinstalled old RAM and laptop boots fine. My understanding from review of this site is that when adding RAM should not require any modification steps in Ubuntu it should just boot.

Comment: If you just installed RAM, I'd not be trying to boot your normal OS until you've validated your 'new' memory.  I'd be booting a 'live' system, or anything that has memtest86 & run that a day or so, to prove the memory is valid.  If it's faulty you'll potentially only corrupt your installed system and it's data, so I hope you have backups.  Test your memory using the laptop tools first (some tools only test 1 byte out of every 256, esp POST routines so they are fast; ie. to memory's presence and not for errors), then memtest86 from 'live' system (8+ hours), then treat it as trustworthy.

Comment: If no errors accure duriing memtest, then put your old one in and show `sudo dmidecode -t 16` there you can see how much your board can handle.

Comment: @T. Moscow Works with old memory, fails with new? Take the new back and get the right RAM this time. That's a slam-dunk hardware issue.

Comment: Did you check to see how much ram could be installed?